# seeInDatabase fails sometimes because of updated_at fields 1sec later

Tags: laravel, testing

I have a test in Laravel 5.7 that pass 90% of the time.

sometimes, it fails, and it is because there is a second between created_at and updated_at:

In DB:

```
"created_at" => "2019-01-23 18:27:36"
"updated_at" => "2019-01-23 18:27:37"
```

Inside local setting $setting:

```
"created_at" => "2019-01-23 18:27:36"
"updated_at" => "2019-01-23 18:27:36"
```

my test:

```
/** @test */
    public function it_update_setting_for_championship()
    {
        $tournament = factory(Tournament::class)->create();
        $championship = factory(Championship::class)->create(['tournament_id' => $tournament->id, 'category_id' => 2]);
        $setting = factory(ChampionshipSettings::class)->create(['championship_id' => $championship->id]);

        $this->call('PUT', '/championships/' . $championship->id . '/settings/' . $setting->id, $setting->toArray());
        $this->assertResponseOk();
        $this->seeInDatabase('championship_settings', $setting->toArray());
    }
```

Of course, I could put `$setting->toArray()` into a variable and `unset` `created_at` and `updated_at` but it feels wrong...

Why doesn't it happen always ?

Anybody has a better solution?

EDIT:

ChampionshipSettingsFactory:

```
$factory->define(ChampionshipSettings::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) use ($factory) {
    $tcs = Championship::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();

    return [
        'championship_id' => $faker->randomElement($tcs),
        'teamSize' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 6),
        'fightingAreas' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'fightDuration' => "03:00",
        'hasPreliminary' => $faker->boolean(),
        'preliminaryWinner' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 2),
        'hasEncho' => $faker->boolean(),
        'enchoQty' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'enchoDuration' => "01:00",
        'hasHantei' => $faker->boolean(),
        'cost' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 100),
        'preliminaryGroupSize' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
        'preliminaryDuration' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
        'seedQuantity' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'hanteiLimit' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10), // 1/2 Finals
        'enchoGoldPoint' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10), // Step where Encho has no more time limit
        'limitByEntity' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Are you using timestamps in your championship model? Can you also show us your  `ChampionshipSettings` factory?

Comment: edited ChampionshipSettingsFactory! in my model, I have protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is how you are running your factory. You are are creating the element in your database and then overwriting the value after creating it.

A weird *quirk* with factories is that they will always run the factory code and then apply you're overwrites unless you use a function as the value in the `key => value` pair.

Change you're factory to the below so that you use a function for your ID instead:

```
$factory->define(ChampionshipSettings::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'championship_id' => function() {
            // Setting the id to a function makes it so the below query doesn't run
            // If we do an overwrite when we are using this factory.
            return Championship::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
        },
        'teamSize' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 6),
        'fightingAreas' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'fightDuration' => "03:00",
        'hasPreliminary' => $faker->boolean(),
        'preliminaryWinner' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 2),
        'hasEncho' => $faker->boolean(),
        'enchoQty' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'enchoDuration' => "01:00",
        'hasHantei' => $faker->boolean(),
        'cost' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 100),
        'preliminaryGroupSize' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
        'preliminaryDuration' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
        'seedQuantity' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 4),
        'hanteiLimit' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10), // 1/2 Finals
        'enchoGoldPoint' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10), // Step where Encho has no more time limit
        'limitByEntity' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 10),
    ];
});
```

So to now when you run:

```
$setting = factory(ChampionshipSettings::class)->create([
    'championship_id' => $championship->id
]);
```

You will no longer be running the query to go to the database to look for championship IDs even if you are overwriting them as shown above.

This method is mentioned (with little detail as to why) in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#relationships

Let me know if the problem still happens.